# Centering oversized image in responsive div

Tags: css, responsive-images

I have been researching this issue for the last few days, and while have found several solutions that work well in static layouts, I am having a problem resolving in responsive design.

We have a series of banner images that we use on our home page, and are trying to get them to appear centered on the image behind text on smaller mobile screens.  I can solve this for fixed widths, but we need to make this responsive.

Here is what the current rendition of my CSS code looks like:

```
#mainSlideshow .item img {
    display: block;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    height: 350px !important; 
    overflow: hidden;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform:  translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform:  translateX(-50%);
-o-transform:  translateX(-50%);
transform:  translateX(-50%);
}
#mainSlideshow .item .carouselImgHold {position: relative; }
```

The challenge appears to be the movement left - right now, the image just shifts to the left 50% of the img width (no surprise).  How do I program the CSS to drift the image only the amount necessary to center the image in the nested div tag?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also provide your HTML?  Or better yet, a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use text-align and negative margins if IMG stands alone on its line.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPpYzM

```css
.oversizedImage {
  text-align: center;
}

.oversizedImage img {
  margin: 0 -100%;
}
/* demo purpose */

.oversizedImage {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 150px 100px white;/* you should use overflow:hidden; here it only shows how much is outside :) */
}

.oversizedImage img {
  vertical-align: top;
  /* instead default baseline to avoid gap under */  
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="oversizedImage">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/200"/>
</div>
```

It is only a guess since we miss your HTML

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you could give us an example but lets try. :)

My suggestion is to set image as `background-image` instead of linking it. So that would look like:

```
#mainSlideshow .item{
  background-image:url("path-to-image/image.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

That way you will have not stretched image covering the `#mainSlideshow .item` .Read more about that [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this to ways.

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

Or

```
img {
    width: 50%
    left: 50%
}
```